# Can't move files to SD card

Tags: external-sd, sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia M2 (not rooted) on 4.4 kitkat, and recently it started giving errors whenever it tries to move files to my external SD card. My internal storage is almost full, and it sometimes gives me notifications to move files to my external SD to clear up space. However when I tap it to actually move files, it fails with

```
Transfer interrupted. Check SD card for partially copied files.
```

In fact, no apps seem to be able to write to the SD card at all. In terminal emulator, I get this

```
$ cd /storage/sdcard1
$ mkdir test
Failed to create 'test': permission denied
```

What happened, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Related question (unresolved - though I believe 3rd party file tools have specifically been excluded from these rights since KitKat) - [http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86251/receiving-an-eaccess-permission-denied-error-when-copying-files-to-extsdcard](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86251/receiving-an-eaccess-permission-denied-error-when-copying-files-to-extsdcard)

Comment: Note: **not even the *android system* is able to access my SD.** I know kitkat disallows app SD access, but I think this is a bigger problem.