# With stock lollipop, how do I edit/copy/paste/move file onto the external sd card?

Tags: external-sd, 5.1-lollipop, file-management, es-file-explorer

I have the stock Google Play Edition of the LG G Pad 8.3. It is essentially a nexus device, stock lollipop, but also has an SD card slot.

I want to use ES File Explorer to manage files on the SD card but cannot figure out how to give it permission.  It pops up with this image:
[image]
but selecting to show the SD card does not actually show the external SD card (actually toggling this on/off seems to do nothing).

How do I manage files on the external SD card using ES File Explorer?  As far as I can tell, there is no stock file manager to do this.

Comment: Related question - [http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86251/receiving-an-eaccess-permission-denied-error-when-copying-files-to-extsdcard](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86251/receiving-an-eaccess-permission-denied-error-when-copying-files-to-extsdcard)

Comment: Related but that post says restrictions will be adjusted in lollipop. I'm using lollipop and the app mentions a way to give it permissions, it just doesn't work.