# Is it possible to use adb to push to the extSdCard (Samsung S3, getting permission denied error)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, adb

I am trying to push a media file to a rooted Samsung S3 running Samsung's stock Android 4.3. I have tried

```
$ adb push file /storage/extSdCard
failed to copy file to '/storage/extSdCard/file`: Permission denied
```

I think it's due to

```
drwxrwxr-x system   media_rw          2016-01-29 21:03 extSdCard
```

and the `shell` user not being in `media_rw`. I tried to `chmod 777 /storage/extSdCard` but the permissions don't change.

Having read various answers and other content (such as work-arounds) on the web without success, I'm left wondering if it's possible on the S3 to use adb to write to the SD Card ?

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111576) would imply that it isn't possible, but hopefully that isn't the case?

Comment: Elevate to a root shell with SU command to get the #.

Comment: Yes that works in `adb shell` but I don't think you can do `su'` with `adb push`  as far as I know...

Comment: Try running "adb root" to enable adbd to run as root before pushing and see if that helps

Comment: Do you've a Nandroid backup? You can mess up with few things here, to see what works out. For example, change the group from `media_rw` to `sdcard_rw` recursively and see how it works out. SELinux may also be involved here so you may also have to take care of it.